# Scala/Play/Akka: remote application to application communication

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

If I have two Scala/Play applications on different servers, what would be the best way for them to communicate for sending small bits of data both ways?

1. RESTful approach
2. Akka remote actors
3. Something else?

I was initially thinking about Akka remote actors, but there's one question that I can't find answer for: how is authorisation between the two applications handled in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “small bits of data” part would fit Akka remoting quite well, but as you note there is nothing at the transport level which could be used to perform authentication or authorization: Akka systems trust each other implicitly (the background is that remoting has been developed with clusters in mind). You can of course include the necessary security tokens (hashes, signatures, etc.) in your messages and perform the checking yourself in the receiving actors, and you can also limit which actor paths can be looked up from outside of the system, see [the 2.3.0 documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.0/scala/remoting.html#Remote_Security).

If on the other hand you have an established infrastructure for authentication and authorization on the HTTP layer, then you might be better off using RESTful APIs with that instead.